# R output dissimilarity matrix

Tags: r

I m new to R
I want to export from R a file with a dissimilarity matrix. By that time I have written:

```
  x<-read.table("C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\R\\new all.csv",
              header=T,sep=";",row.names=1)
  library(betapart)
  beta<-beta.pair(x[,1:192], index.family="sorensen")
```

Which function should I use to export it?
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you check `str(beta)`, you'll notice that `beta` is a list of the following three elements, each of class `dist`: `beta.sim`, `beta.sne`, and `beta.sor`. You can export each element of `beta` using the `write.csv()` or the `write.table()` functions as @pogonomyrmex suggests, but first you need to start by specifying each of the elements of `beta` as a `matrix` instead of a `dist`:

```
m.sim <- as.matrix(beta$beta.sim)
m.sne <- as.matrix(beta$beta.sne)
m.sor <- as.matrix(beta$beta.sor)
```

Then you can export each of the matrices individually:

```
write.csv(m.sim, "sim.csv")
write.csv(m.sne, "sne.csv")
write.csv(m.sor, "sor.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `write.table(beta, "file.txt")` function to output a text file. If you want a csv file, use either `write.csv()` or add the `sep=","` argument to the write.table function.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but it appears again Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class '"dist"' into a data.frame. Do you know what is it

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed that "beta" is a data frame, @smillig already gave a much better reply.